# Replacing strings retrieved from database - Laravel & Shopify

Tags: php, laravel

I have created and registered my Shopify Web-hooks which are working perfectly. When a customer places an order, an sms notification is sent to the customer.

The sms notification content is saved in the database and retrieved when the web-hook is triggered for the sms to be sent. In the database, the sms notification content is saved as **"Thank you for placing order %order_number%"**.

When the sms is sent to the client, the string `%order_number%` should be replaced with the actual order number to be as **"Thank you for placing order 13"**.

This is what i have now

**Controller**

```
public function orderPlaceWebhook(Request $request)
{

     //get order details
     $order = $request->getContent();   
     $order = json_decode($order, true);
     $order_number = $order['number'];

     //fetched sms notification template from db
     $Message = SMS::where('site', Auth::user()->site);
    //message content saved is "Thank you for placing order %order_number%"

     //send sms
     $baseurl = "https://apps.domain.com/smsapi";
     $query = "?key=$keyto=$number&msg=$Message&sender_id=$sender";
     $final_uri = $baseurl.$query;
     $response = file_get_contents($final_uri);
     header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
}
```

How can i replace the string `%order_number%` in `$Message` with the value coming from `$order_number` ?

PS: Thank you in advance. Beginner with laravel

Comment: Why not simply do `$Message = "Thank you for placing order $order_number";`

Comment: why not just use $order_number inside $message?

Comment: @Phil, so when saving the template to my database, i should save it as ` "Thank you for placing order $order_number" ?` I only displayed the $Message content in the code to let you know how it is being stored in the database

Answer (score 1):

Is there a special reason why you keep the template in the DB? 
Wouldn't it be better to use a translation file, and later if you need to support different languages it will be much easier.

so you can have in a translation file message like:

```
'sms_template' => 'Thank you for placing order :order'
```

in Laravel then use

```
trans('MESSAGE_FILE_NAME.sms_template', ['order' => $order_number]);
```

replace the MESSAGE_FILE_NAME with your translation file.

If you still need to use the plain old PHP way then do this:

```
str_replace("%order_number%", $order_number, $Message);
```

Comment: What about if the user wants to change the content of the `sms_template`?  Because a lot of users are using the system. Where would the user's new content be ?

Comment: I thought it is a system based template not a user based. So if it should be custom message then use the `str_replace` function to perform what you want.